# Unable to take Screen Shoot on test failure

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I've been having trouble with taking screenshot on failure when I run my Automation project.

This is the error I am getting in my Extent report:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]   at
> org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:110)   at
> org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:1413)     at
> org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:56)  at
> org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:66)  at
> TestCases.dummyTest.test1(dummyTest.java:11)  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:673)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:220)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)   at
> org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)     at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)   at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)  at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)   at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> base.baseClass.getScreenShotPath(baseClass.java:26)   at
> listeners.customListeners.onTestFailure(customListeners.java:48)  at
> org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:99)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runTestResultListener(TestInvoker.java:276)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:744)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:220)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at
> org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)   at
> org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)     at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)   at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)  at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)   at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)

My dummyTest:

```
    package TestCases;

import base.baseClass;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class dummyTest extends baseClass {

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Here is my base Class:

```
  package base;

import PageFactory.dodax.homepagePageFactory;
import PageFactory.dodax.loginPageFactory;
import PageFactory.dodax.shoppingCartPageFactory;
import PageFactory.dodax.wishListPageFactory;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class baseClass {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    //private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(homePage_test.class.getName());
    public String getScreenShotPath(String testCaseName, WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String destinationFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\reports\\" + testCaseName + ".png";
        System.out.println(destinationFile);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(destinationFile));
        return destinationFile;
    }

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:exe\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String baseURL = "https://www.dodax.ca";
        driver.get(baseURL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();


    }

    //    Moze da ima 2 before test, edniot so atributi i edniot be atributi;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setOff() {
        homepagePageFactory homepagePF = new homepagePageFactory(driver);
        wishListPageFactory wishListPF = new wishListPageFactory(driver);
        loginPageFactory loginPF = new loginPageFactory(driver);
        shoppingCartPageFactory shoppingPF = new shoppingCartPageFactory(driver);

       homepagePF.clickCookiesPF();
        homepagePF.signUpButton();
        loginPF.logIn();
        homepagePF.clickWishListButton();
        wishListPF.removeWishListItems();
        wishListPF.waitForEmptyWishList();
        homepagePF.openCart();
        shoppingPF.removeShoppingCartItems();
        loginPF.logOut();

    }



    @AfterTest
    public void logOut() {
        homepagePageFactory homepagePF = new homepagePageFactory(driver);
        try {
            homepagePF.logOut();
        } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void closeBrowser() {

      driver.quit();

    }
}
```

My customListeners Class:

```
    package listeners;

import base.ExtentReporter;
import base.baseClass;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

import java.io.IOException;

public class customListeners extends baseClass implements ITestListener {

    WebDriver driver = null;
    ExtentTest test;
    ExtentReports extent = ExtentReporter.getReportObject();
    ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> extentTest = new ThreadLocal<ExtentTest>();


    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        // When test method starts
        test = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        extentTest.set(test);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        // If test method is successful
        extentTest.get().log(Status.PASS, "Test Passed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        extentTest.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
        WebDriver driver = null;
        String testMethodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();

        try {
            driver = (WebDriver) result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getDeclaredField("driver").get(result.getInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        try {
            extentTest.get().addScreenCaptureFromPath(getScreenShotPath(testMethodName, driver), result.getMethod().getMethodName());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        // If test method is failed
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        // Ignore this
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        // Before <test> tag of xml file

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        extent.flush();
    }

}
```

My POM.XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dodax</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java/base</directory>
<!--<filtering>true</filtering>-->
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
<!--<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>-->
                    <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testngDummy.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        <!-- <suiteXmlFile>suites-test-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>-->
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Compiler plugin configures the java version to be used for compiling
                the code -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>3.8.1</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: You have a null pointer exception.

Comment: I know that, any suggestions for how to fix that??

Comment: My mistake was in customListeners class, I had to delete Webdriver driver = null;